# Compare the values in two different arrays

Tags: arrays, compare, swift2

I am trying to compare the values of two arrays in Swift. If a value of `array2` is not found in `array1` all the `array2` found values need to be list and deleted.

I was trying to use the code below but its not working anymore in Swift 2:

```
let array1 = [["aaa","12"],["bbb","349"],["ccc","91"],["ddd","143"]]
let array2 = ["aaa","SSS","bbb","ccc","QQQ","ZZZ","ddd"]

let notNeededValues = filter(enumerate(zip(array1,array2))) { $1.0 == $1.1 }.map{ $0.0 }

print(notNeededValues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but the problem seems to be, that your code needs a simple conversion to Swift 2 syntax:

```
let array1 = [["aaa","12"],["bbb","349"],["ccc","91"],["ddd","143"]]
let array2 = ["aaa","SSS","bbb","ccc","QQQ","ZZZ","ddd"]

let notNeededValues = zip(array1, array2).enumerate().filter { $1.0 == $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }

print(notNeededValues)
```

Swift is moving away from globally defined functions, like `filter` and `enumerate` once were, and is using dot-syntax instead. This change was made possible by protocol extensions, and makes code more readable.

---

**Update:**

I assume this is what you mean(?):

```
let notNeededValues = array2.filter { !array1.map { $0[0] }.contains($0) }

// or like this:
let array1FirstElements = array1.map { $0[0] }
let notNeededValues = array2.filter { !array1FirstElements.contains($0) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My problem is that I need to find, list the values that are not matching in the two arrays and delete those values from array2

Comment: Well `array1` is an array of arrays. Do I only compare the first value with the values in `array2`? What is your use-case for `array1`? To me it looks like a `[String: String]` (dictionary) would be better suited.

Comment: Yes just the first values need to be compared. The array1 is a JSON list that contains videos uploaded

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
let array1 = [["aaa","12"],["bbb","349"],["ccc","91"],["ddd","143"]]
let array2 = ["aaa","SSS","bbb","ccc","QQQ","ZZZ","ddd"]

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func removeObject(object: Element) -> [Element] {
        return filter {$0 != object}
    }
}

var filteredArray2 = array2.reduce(array2) {
    if array1.flatMap({$0}).contains($1) {
        return $0.removeObject($1)
    }
    return $0
}

print(filteredArray2)
```